Do almost all polynomials of degree $n$ in $\mathbb R[x]$ have exactly $n$ distinct roots in $\mathbb C$?
It follows from the fundamental theorem of algebra that, if $P(x)\in\mathbb R[x]$ is a nonzero polynomial of degree $n$, then $P(x)$ has at most $n$ distinct roots in $\mathbb C$ (to be precise, it has exactly $n$ roots if counted with their multiplicity).
But do almost all (in the sense of measure theory) polynomials of degree $n$ have exactly $n$ distinct roots in $\mathbb C$?
If we consider polynomials of degree $2$ it's clearly the case, since the set of all $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb R^3$ such that $b^2-4ac=0$ has Lebesgue measure equal to $0$ in $\mathbb R^3$. But of course this reasoning cannot be applied in general. So how can this concept be generalized? Does the statement hold for any degree?
Thanks in advance.
Edit: solved, thanks to the commenters. It was actually much simpler than I thought.

Consider: the measure of an $n-1$ dimensional subspace in $n$ dimensional space is zero.

For each fixed degree you can generalize what you did for degree $2$. Polynomials of any degree have a discriminant, which is a polynomial in the coefficients. (the higher the degree, the more complicated it is, but this doesn't make a difference)

@Mark got it, thanks.

Please either answer your own question or delete it, so that it does not linger on the unanswered queue.

As mentioned in the comments, the space of polynomials having $<n$ roots has a dimension smaller than $n$, so they have measure zero.
